# Why is <p> is being pushed out of <div>?

Tags: html, css, overflow

A `<p>` tag, that is supposed to be inside a `<div>` tag in code, is stacked under it when the website shows.

The paragraph with id "p1" needs to be displayed inside the div with id "text".

I'd like to draw your attention to the three big boxes to the left of the screen.

Box 1: This box is empty.
Box 2: This is the one that says 'Career'. 
Box 3: The box under is the div I'm having problems with. The text just below it is the text that needs to be in the div. This div's id is "text", and the one it should look similar to is "main".

```css
#banner {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 71px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
#button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 71px;
}
#fixbutton {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid;
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 71px;
}
#main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 204px;
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
}
#picture {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 575px;
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
}
#text {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 650px;
  width: 23%;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
#additionaltext {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 575px;
  width: 21%;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid;
}
#p1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
}
#button:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
#fixbutton:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="banner" id="banner"></div>
  <a href="index.html">
    <div id="button">
      <p id="p1">Home</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="about.html">
    <div id="button">
      <p id="p1">About Me</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="career.html">
    <div id="button">
      <p id="p1">Career</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="school.html">
    <div id="fixbutton">
      <p id="p1">Schooling</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div id="main">
    <p align="center" style="font-size:400%">Career</p>
  </div>
  <div id="picture">
    <img height="575" width="751" src="4-photos.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="additionaltext"></div>
  
  <!-- THE DIV -->
  <div id="text">
    <!-- THE PARA -->
    <p id="p1">My dream career would be art. I really want to be able to draw concept art, background art, storyboards, character art, and animate 2D (and maybe 3D) assets as well.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can`t access multiple divs and p tags with the same id use class="p1" and in the css instead of # use a .(point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the Div with Id="text" the put the P tag with ID p1 into the id="additionaltext". and in your css remove the style for the ID text.
I tried it and it worked fine

Comment: Would you mind going in to a bit more detail there? Or maybe show what you did? I tried to follow along your comment but the wording is a bit confusing and I ended up screwing things up more so I'm back to square 1.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in a way to where I can preserve the original format. I would like that specific text on the left side and I was planning to type something else in the div you used.

Comment: Then perhaps it would be more helpful if you can provide the output you're looking for, I mean how do you wanna distribute the content in your page.

Comment: @PonderingPeridot try adding clear:both into your css in Id="text" to clear the floats like so. https://jsfiddle.net/f9948sm7/12/

Comment: Oh, well that solves the text being in the div problem, but now the div won't be under "main" and next to "picture"

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9948sm7/16/)

```
<div> All divs of the line </div>
<div> All divs in the next block</div>
```

It is better to allways create divs for each line and then you can style their widths relativly to its parent div so they have for example to sum up 100% in width when they are placed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `float` property changes how the DOM layout appears on the screen.

Some resources you should review to help understand what is happening:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/